# how to allow one specific application to access command-prompt?

Tags: active-directory, java, windows-command-prompt

is there a workaround to allow only one specific application to access command prompt (java application) in a disabled command prompt active directory environment without enabling command prompt for the users or other applications

Comment: Is this java app trying to run a BAT or CMD file?

Comment: the java app need to start the ms office word application